# Selling Monthly Online Services

Tags: php, html, open-source, authentication, e-commerce

I am wondering if anyone knows of a system (open source or otherwise) that will allow my clients to sell their online services per month/year/etc.  In other words, the user buys a month subscription, can log in, and access anything that my clients choose for them to see.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: amember pro is the way to go, check it out, cost a little money but worth every cent

Comment: Just go with https://stripe.com/

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard of [Spreedly](http://www.spreedly.com/)? Spreedly isn't a hosted solution it's a SaaS but has a really easy to use API.

Comment: Hi SePP: Their website looks really nice.  I'll definitely take a closer look.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Membergate](http://www.membergate.com)?

Comment: Hi John: Membergate looks good, I'll do some more research on it and post back if I have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this a while back and I almost purchased [aMember Pro](http://www.amember.com/).

Comment: +1 I highly reccomentd amember pro I have used it on several sites in the past, it has integration to allow payment from like 30 different payment processors, also you are able to integrate with forums and all kinds of things, if you choose to, if you only want a member area, that is easy to do as well with amember.  Amember has been being actively developed for at least the past 5-6 years and is still being updated, simply put it has more features and is coded then anything else you will find out there, also the admin panel is just awsome.

Comment: @jasondavis I have a related question that perhaps you can answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8848023/105539

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Spreedly.com

There is also Chargify.com, Recurly.com, and some others.  See:
http://buyersvote.com/categories/the-best-subscription-billing-systems

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/)? Drupal also has an [e-commerce](http://drupal.org/project/ecommerce) module.

Comment: Hi Randell: Does Magento/Drupal have a online content subscription system?  I'm not seeming to find it.

Comment: I believe so.  Checkout http://drupal.org/project/subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

My company is currently using [WHMCS](http://whmcs.com). It's not perfect to be honest but it's a commercial solution that fills our similar needs.