# What's the Technique for Building Domain Packages in AMember?

Tags: payment-gateway, subscriptions, multiple-domains, amember

I want to use AMember to have people purchase WordPress plugins and themes. However, I want to sell different prices for single domain vs. letting them install like 5-domain packs (and multiples of those). One would go through the AMember workflow to purchase something, and then receive a serial number based on their purchase. They activate the theme or plugin and then put in this serial number in an options panel, and they're off and running with a functioning plugin or theme.

What is the most efficient way to tweak the programming of AMember to accommodate per-domain installations of stuff sold through AMember?

For instance, I was thinking perhaps I need to use this Add Field feature, but then use custom programming against that field.

Comment: I tried posting the question here (http://www.amember.com/forum/threads/creating-per-domain-wordpress-plugin-theme-registrations.14024/) but it was not answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently, aMember Pro v4 ability to handle products with quantity is disabled. I am working right now to rework and enable this functionality. Once it is done, it will be easy to do what you are asking for, and I will provide a code snippet with explanation.

If you need it ASAP, contact me directly via helpdesk (attn. to Alex Scott) and I will help you to solve you task.

Comment: Great. Look forward to it. We're still finishing the touches on our plugin and theme, and getting the page designs completed on our payment workflow, so we'll look for your solution soon that we can drop in.

Comment: In this effort, we need to be able to sell the same product to a customer an unlimited amount of times, but that customer can install each product license with only one domain. To make it simple, we've decided to avoid the 5-pack, 10-pack license and just sell the customer one license, one domain, and they purchase repeatedly. Then, we hope to use coupon codes to provide discounts for people purchasing more than one product unit.

Comment: 5-pack, 10-pack license selling is now possible - just implemented that ability. If you contact us via helpdesk, we will provide you with a module we are using for aMember license sales. Specify ticket subject as "Attn: To Alex Scott"

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I haven't used amember in a long time ( I would use it in a heartbeat if I need a member area I just don't need one at the moment) so I really don't know a lot about whats going on in the code as I haven't seen it in so long.

I would assume you would code a custom solution to create the serial numbers and then when a payment is made, you would just have it fire off a call to your custom code to create the serial and add it into the DB, a custom filed would be perfect to hold that value.  If I understand you correctly aMember would be basically used just to handle that serial number for that user, they buy the serial through aMember, aMember handles the buying and expiring and all that for you so it sounds like a pretty straight forward deal

If I misunderstood your question let me know and I will try to improve my answer for you

Comment: Nope, you understood exactly. That's what I'm looking to accomplish. Just thought perhaps someone had done this before and I could save some time. Either that, or someone could show me an easier way in AMember, using a feature I didn't know about, for instance.